# how to connect managed aws apache airflow with cloud9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I created cloud9 in same vpc as managed apache airflow and want to write code and interact with airflow.

also added access key creds to my cloud9 and can see and create resources like s3, lambda etc.

should i install astro cli in cloud9 and connect it to airflow?
or should it be connected from http connection on the airflow side - adding http connector?

edit: managed to create airflow login token with a command

```
aws mwaa create-cli-token --name myapache-airflow-de-project > token-airflow-cluster.txt
```

it creates the login token:

```
"CliToken": "SOmestuff",
"WebServerHostname": "1111.us-east1.airflow.amazonaws.com"
```

installed astro cli on cloud9 but suspect it works only with astronomer.io based airflow clusters.

however i m trying to login using

```
"astro login --token-link somestuff"
```

it gives

```
You are logging into Astro via an OAuth token
This token will expire in 24 hours and will not refresh

Error: cannot retrieve userinfo: API error (401): Unauthorized
```

since it says "logging into astro" - this means astro cli does not work with aws managed airflow? it cant even login to there?

Comment: i figured out the basic workflow does not need any connection or auth with running mwaa - just use aws cli to upload dag file to specified s3 bucket and folder. the dag will be shown and run